# Which authentication gems work for an API using mongoid?

Tags: authentication

I"m familiar with devise and omniauth and that they work for mongoid3, but I'm wondering if there is anything else that I may not be considering?  For example, does authlogic work with mongoid3?  I"m not sure where i can find this information.  Are there any proposed solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like authlogic uses active_record, so I think i'll either stick with nifty-generators or just use devise.

http://cl.ly/image/1V0r0z0q2g2K